# VBA RunAll Macros is inserting duplicate columns

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am trying to combine two macros that I created into a single `RunALL` macro. What I have used for the `RunAll` macro is below. What is happens when I use the `RunAll` macro, it creates two columns with the same name. I tried to attach photo on here for you to see as example.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub RunAll()
    Call CopyWorkbook
    Call InsertColumn
End Sub
```

CopyWorkbook macro is ...

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet

    'copy from the source
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\Safety\Chris A\Employee Safety   Profile\Speeding_Report.xlsm"
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Report")
    sourceSheet.Activate
    sourceSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy

    'paste to the destination
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\Safety\Chris A\Employee Safety Profile\Employee_Safety_Profile.xlsm"
    Set destSheet = Worksheets("Speeding")
    destSheet.Activate
    destSheet.Cells.Select
    destSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

InsertColumn macro is....

```
Sub InsertColumn()
    Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("E9").Value = "Full Name"

    Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("F9").Value = "UUID"     
End Sub
```

[image: Photo of Duplicate Columns]

Comment: Can't replicate this - are you sure the columns don't already exist on the sheet you're copying from?

Comment: No, they don’t already show up, when I wrote it and ran the macro by itself it worked perfect. But, when I created the “RunAll” macro and added the call functions, that’s when the extra set of columns showed up. I wrote another macro after posting this to delete those columns, created another step. I was hoping their was another way to fix it, instead of creating another step for it go through.

Comment: Are you using the "InsertColumn" function anywhere else in your code?  This looks like a situation where you have code being called by an event (for example "Workbook_Activate", "Workbook_Open" and "Worksheet_Change"  would all be triggered by your "CopyWorkbook" function).

Comment: No, I am not using the "InsertColumn" function anywhere else.